# Is there a way to run selenium server without Admin rights in Windows 7?

Tags: selenium

When I worked in XP, I was able to run selenium server without Admin rights.
However, in Windows 7, I'm unable to run it unless I run it as Admin.

For my organization's security policy, we need to run it as regular user but it gets stopped runnning since you are not admin.

Any idea? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you need to have an admin give privileges for a program to bind to port 4444 (the default for Selenium) or whatever port you're using. This answer at ServerFault may help your administrator set that up. https://serverfault.com/questions/246796/use-port-binding-permissions-on-windows